# what is the the equivalent of this code(c#) on vb?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, razor

good morning ,
I'm searching for the equivalent of this code(c#) on vb :

```
@Html.DropDownList("cityId", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Cities, new { id = "cityId" })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Html.DropDownList("cityId", DirectCast(ViewBag.Cities, IEnumerable(Of SelectListItem)), New With { _
    Key .id = "cityId" _
})`

Answer (score 1):

It should be this in VB.NET:

```
Html.DropDownList("cityId", DirectCast(ViewBag.Cities, IEnumerable(Of SelectListItem)), New With { Key.id = "cityId" })
```